# Does the behaviour of the Java garbage collector evolve over time or get impacted by JIT?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jit

We have a production web application running on our intranet which:

- is restarted at 0300 each day in order to perform a backup of its database
- has the same load on it throughout the working day (0800 to 1700)
- is running on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM version 20.45-b01
- is running on a physical machine with 16 cores and 32 gigs of RAM, running Linux 2.6.18-128.el5
- does not share the machine with any other significant process
- is configured with:

  ```
  -Xms2g
  -XX:PermSize=256m
  -Xmx4g
  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
  -Xss192k
  -XX:+UseParNewGC
  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
  -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
  -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50
  -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
  ```

Each day the heap usage:

- rises gradually to 90% from startup until 0800
- remains at 90% until 0930
- remains at 70% from 0930 until 1415
- drops to 50% at 1415
- drops to 37% at 1445

at which point the heap rises to 55% in about 40 minutes and is collected back to 37%, ad infinitum until the next restart.

We have AppDynamics installed on the JVM and can see that Major Garbage Collections take place roughly every minute without much of an impact on the memory (except the falls outlined above of course) until the memory reaches 37%, when the Major collections become much less frequent.

There are obviously hundreds of factors external to the behaviour of a web application, but one avenue of research is the fact that Hotspot JIT information is obviously lost when the JVM is stopped.

Are there GC optimisations/etc which are also lost with the shutdown of the JVM? Is the JVM effectively consuming more memory than it needs to because certain Hotspot optimisations haven't yet taken place?

Is it possible that we would get better memory performance from this application if the JVM wasn't restarted and we found another way to perform a backup of the database?

(Just to reiterate, I know that there are a hundred thousand things that could influence the behaviour of an application, especially an application that hardly anyone else knows! I really just want to know whether there are certain things to do with the memory performance of a JVM which are lost when it is stopped)

Comment: I don't know anything about it, although I doubt that full JIT optimization kicks in only after 6 hours of running (0930 the memory usage is maximal and drops afterwards). For me this looks rather like a garbage collection that is too lazy initially. What happens if you start with -Xmx3g? Does it run out of memory?

Comment: I would be most likely to believe that, after the first hour or so, most of the fluctuations you see are due to workload changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for the behaviour of GCs to change over time due to JIT optimisation. One example is 'Escape Analysis' which has been enabled by default since Java 6u23. This type of optimisation can prevent some objects from being created in the heap and therefore not require garbage collection at all.

For more information see [Java 7's HotSpot Performance Enhancements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis).